# Is the following statement a hadith: “If a person eats seven ajwa dates, poison and magic will not affect him”?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

A philosopher denies a hadith that he says exists in Kutub as-Sitta. What is the interpretation of this hadith? 
"If a person eats seven ajwa dates in the morning, poison and magic will not affect him until the night."
- He accuses the hadith of being illogical. What is the explanation of the hadith?

Comment: First you need to investigate the authenticity of a hadith before you search for its meaning , there are plenty of weak "unauthentic" hadiths that have very strange incidents or explanations to them , so before any effort to interpret , always check the authenticity first .

Answer (score 1):

This Hadith was narrated on the authority of Sa'd bin Abi Waqqas and reported by Bukhari (5445), Muslim (2047) and Abu Dawud (3876). It also occurs with At-Tirmidhi (2066) on the authority of Abu Hurariah with different wording and again with Ibn Majah (3453) on the authority of Abu Sa'id and Jabir. This type of ripe date is especially nutritious. It grows in Madinah and most of the scholars hold it applies only to this specific date.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. (see [answer]).

Comment: Actually, it does. The first question was 'is it a Hadith?' This was answered: Bukhari, Muslim, Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi and Ibn Majah. The second question was 'is it authentic?' This was answered by the fact that it's in Bukhari and Muslim. The third question was 'what is its explanation?' The answer to that is 'it is a type of ripe date that is especially  nutritious and grows in Madinah' and 'the majority of the scholars say it is specific for this type of date'.

Comment: No there's only a question about the interpretation or explanation of the hadith. This doesn't really explain it. As OP actually points at the fact that it appears in the 6 books you've quoted. So he didn't look for this information.

Comment: I see you like talking and have absolutely nothing to benefit people with. The questioner asked 2 questions. 1: Is it a Hadith? and 2: What is its interpretation or explanation? The answer was "This HADITH was narrated..." which answers the first question. The second question was answered by "This type of ripe date... to this specific date." Because that is what the scholars explained it as. If you have a better explanation then benefit us.